# Couldn't setup OpenGL for the requested monitor resolution Hearthstone Linux

Tags: linux, graphics-card, hearthstone

When I try to run Hearthstone I get the error mentioned in the heading and in the following body:

```
GLContext: failed to share context 40000: Success.

Screen: could not setup GL for resolution (1024x600 fs=1 hz=0 window=262330)
GLContext: failed to share context 30002: Success.

Screen: could not setup GL for resolution (800x587 fs=0 hz=60 window=262330)
```

I checked on the requirements and my graphics card is supported for Hearthstone and I do not know how to fix this error? Also I am running it under Linux via wine.

Thanks to everyone who lost their time here! {:

Comment: Identical question in a different website: http://askubuntu.com/questions/432637/issues-with-wine-screen-resolution